If "carry" is transitive in "I worked as a puppet trained to scrub and carry, curtsy and nod", then what is the object?
In the sentence:

I worked as a puppet trained to scrub and carry, curtsy and nod

I think that the verb "carry" is transitive. However, I couldn't tell of the object for it. So, I could only guess that there's an implicit object here, but I am not sure about it. Anyone can help point out the grammar pattern being used here?

Carry can be intransitive. Here the meaning is trained to be a scrubber and carrier (ie just do menial work).

The usual expression is fetch and carry.

The whole sentence is more for its poetic impact than literal meaning, since puppets can't be trained. But yes, there could be an implicit object, and in this vague sentence, it's simply "things that need carrying."

@PeterKirkpatrick So does that mean, when a dog owner shouts "fetch!" but doesn't qualify it with "...the stick", they just want the dog to come back with nothing in its mouth?

The object of a transitive verb can be implied but not stated. Obviously, when 'carry' means to hold something or someone and transport it from one place to another it can only be a transitive verb. You cannot carry nothing! So if someone said they had a job "lifting and carrying" you'd understand they must be carrying something. This is called a null object, or understood object.
If someone describes their job as something like "fetching and carrying" the general implication is that they are doing menial tasks, running errands, delivering messages etc.
The intransitive use of 'carry' is completely different and means continue - for example, we say that a sound "carries" if it has a far reach, and we also have the phrasal verb "to carry on".

I just had a cursor reading into the null object. Before, I also read an article discussing the object's internal state changes made by intransitive verbs, which I found that together with null object concept makes it hard to determine the transitivity of verbs.

@KtStudent Like a lot of language concepts it's harder to explain than actually use. The meaning of a verb is what helps you determine its transitivity, not the presence of an object in the sentence. And I think that's what led to this question - you know something had to be carried but you couldn't see what it was.
